# Why is field update throwing Binding Collection Error

Tags: sql-server, vb6, adodb, visual-studio-6

I have a VB6 app that connects to a SQL Server server by using ***ADODB 2.8***. I have declared the bindings and the recordsets. The information is being shown correctly. Still, when I try to update any field, I get an error saying:

> **Binding Collection Error**
>
> Field not updatable, Bound Property Name: Text, Field Name: DTMOUVEMEN

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the way the ADODB.Recorset is being created, but I have no idea, VB6 is not my field of expertise.

The textBox in my form that is binded to a ADODC is like this

```
  Begin VB.TextBox DTMOUVEMENT 
     BackColor       =   &H00E0E0E0&
     DataField       =   "DTMOUVEMEN"
     DataSource      =   "DataTYPEMOUVEMENTADO"
     Height          =   315
     Left            =   2820
     Locked          =   -1  'True
     TabIndex        =   1
     TabStop         =   0   'False
     Text            =   "DTMOUVEMENT"
     Top             =   2820
     Width           =   2895
  End
```

The ADODC component is defined like this

```
Begin MSAdodcLib.Adodc DataTYPEMOUVEMENTADO 
  Height          =   330
  Left            =   5800
  Top             =   2500
  Width           =   2295
  _ExtentX        =   4048
  _ExtentY        =   582
  ConnectMode     =   0
  CursorLocation  =   3
  IsolationLevel  =   -1
  ConnectionTimeout=   15
  CommandTimeout  =   30
  CursorType      =   3
  LockType        =   3
  CommandType     =   8
  CursorOptions   =   0
  CacheSize       =   50
  MaxRecords      =   0
  BOFAction       =   0
  EOFAction       =   0
  ConnectStringType=   1
  Appearance      =   1
  BackColor       =   -2147483643
  ForeColor       =   -2147483640
  Orientation     =   0
  Enabled         =   -1
  Connect         =   ""
  OLEDBString     =   ""
  OLEDBFile       =   ""
  DataSourceName  =   ""
  OtherAttributes =   ""
  UserName        =   ""
  Password        =   ""
  RecordSource    =   ""
  Caption         =   "DataTYPEMOUVEMENTADO"
  BeginProperty Font {0BE35203-8F91-11CE-9DE3-00AA004BB851} 
     Name            =   "MS Sans Serif"
     Size            =   8.25
     Charset         =   0
     Weight          =   400
     Underline       =   0   'False
     Italic          =   0   'False
     Strikethrough   =   0   'False
  EndProperty
  _Version        =   393216
End
```

The ADODC component is being binded like this

```
strSQL = "here goes the sql query"
Set adoRS = New ADODB.Recordset
With adoRS
    .CursorLocation = adUseServer
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open strSQL, adoDbConn 
End With
Set Me.DataTYPEMOUVEMENTADO.Recordset = adoRS
```

The connection is being defined like this

```
    Set adoDbConn = New ADODB.Connection

    ' Specify the OLE DB provider.
    adoDbConn.Provider = "sqloledb"
    adoDbConn.Mode = adModeReadWrite
    adoDbConn.Open "connection string data"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the error. For this particular case, the SQL query was wrongly defined, so no field ***DTMOUVEMEN*** was being set in the Adodc Recordset.